# Polling Datawarehouse Design

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, data-warehouse

I really need your help.
I am currently working on a BI project for a polling institute.
We have surveys that we do all over the world and I have to create a data warehouse that collects all these polls and analyzes them.
The difficulty I encounter in modeling my datawarehouse is that I have a hundred measures.
I've heard of a modeling in which we put measures as a dimension and we have measures like QTD, YTD.
Would anyone have an example of this type of modeling ???

Thanks for your help

Comment: This question is far too broad. Textbooks could be written on the subject of data warehouse design. StackOverflow might be a good place to refine an existing design; but is not a good place to start from scratch, with questions that have no right or wrong answers.

Comment: Share something to us what you have done already? If you have an example of the design that you have tried or thought to try. The subject is very broad without any details about the use cases.